# Why is the checking for Class not Working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When i check for the class name with .hasClass its not working.

```
function changeClass(){
var elBox = document.getElementById('box');

if(elBox.hasClass('blue')){
 elBox.className = 'red';
}
}

var trigger = document.getElementById('trigger');

trigger.onmouseover = changeClass;
```

But generally its working when i check for attribute for example

```
if(elBox.hasAttribute('class') ....
```

I just don't get why the checking for class fails, maybe someone can help.

Comment: You're confusing DOM and jQuery methods. Learn the difference.

Comment: > IE 8 browsers can use `.classList.contains()` while any javascript can go with `/blue/.test(element.className)` as an example.  The latter is the cheapest check but you won't see a noticeable difference unless you do it a LOT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`elBox` is just a DOM object, wrap it with jQuery wrapper in order to use jQuery methods like `.hasClass()`.

Instead of

```
if(elBox.hasClass('blue')){
```

Use

```
if($(elBox).hasClass('blue')){
```

Comment: @Gregor..happy to help you..;)

Answer (score 0):

`elBox` is a DOM element. You should use jQuery object for using jQuery method `hasClass()`. Try like following.

```
$('#box').hasClass('blue')
```

Or

```
$(elBox).hasClass('blue')
```